# On the Determinant of a Square Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Let $A$ be a square symmetric matrix, if $\textrm{det}(A)=c$, where $c$  is a non- zero real number.
Can we find $\textrm{det}(A)$ if we change only the first entry of $A$; that is, if we replace $(a_{11})$ by $d$ where $d$ is a non-zero real number?

Comment: Have you tried some small examples?

Comment: I didnt, because I dont think it is helpful.

Comment: Well $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ both have determinants of $1$, but what happens if you change their first entries to $d$?

Comment: It is always helpful if you try something yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not with just the information you provided. You'd also need the deteminant of the matrix obtained by eliminating first row and first column from matrix ${\bf A}$.

The determinat is linear in respect of every row and every column of the matrix (assuming the other rows/column are kept constant), so if $${\bf A}=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & {\bf w}^T \\ {\bf v} & {\bf M}\end{bmatrix}$$ and $${\bf A}'=\begin{bmatrix} d & {\bf w}^T \\ {\bf v} & {\bf M}\end{bmatrix}$$
then
$$ \det {\bf A}' = \det \begin{bmatrix} d & {\bf w}^T \\ {\bf v} & {\bf M}\end{bmatrix} = \det \left(\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & {\bf w}^T \\ {\bf v} & {\bf M}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} d-a_{11} & 0 \\ {\bf v} & {\bf M}\end{bmatrix} \right)= \\= \det \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & {\bf w}^T \\ {\bf v} & {\bf M}\end{bmatrix}+ \det\begin{bmatrix} d-a_{11} & 0 \\ {\bf v} & {\bf M}\end{bmatrix} = \\= \det {\bf A} + (d-a_{11} ) \det{\bf M}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Laplace's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace's_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix) for computing determinants. Let $\tilde{A}$ the matrix obtained from $A$ by substituting $a_{1,1}$ for $d$. Denote by $M_{i,j}$ (resp. $\tilde{M}_{i,j}$) "the determinant of the $(n−1) \times (n−1)$-matrix that results from $A$ (resp. $\tilde{A}$) by removing the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column". Then
$$ \det(\tilde{A}) = \sum_j (-1)^{1+j}\tilde{a}_{1,j}\tilde{M}_{i,j}$$
Note that $\tilde{M}_{1,j} = M_{1,j}$ for all $j$ because $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ only differ in the $(1,1)$-th entry. By adding and subtracting $a_{1,1}M_{1,1}$, we get
$$ \det(\tilde{A}) = c + (d-a_{1,1})M_{1,1} $$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), which states that:
$$\det(A + uv^T) = (1 + v^TA^{-1}u)\det(A).$$

Just note that
$$e_1e_1^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and with $B$ being your $A$ matrix with $a_{11}$ replaced with $d$ we get:
$$\det(B) = \det\left(A + (d - a_{11})e_1e_1^T\right) = (1 + (d - a_{11})e_1^TA^{-1}e_1)\det(A)$$
You could apply this directly, solve $Ax = e_1$ to find $x = A^{-1}e_1$ and then just compute the rest.

You can also note that
$$e_1^T A^{-1} e_1 = e_1^Ta^{-1}_1 = a^{-1}_{11}$$
where $a^{-1}_1$ is the first column of $A^{-1}$ and $a_{11}$ is the first element in $a^{-1}_1$. Thus we get:
$$\det(B) = (1 + (d - a_{11})a^{-1}_{11})\det(A)$$

Now, we can compute $a^{-1}_{11}$ using [cofactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)), we have:
$$a^{-1}_{11} = \frac{C_{11}}{\det(A)} $$
where $C_{11}$ is the cofactor that is the determinant of the matrix formed by removing the first row and first column of $A$, let's say it's $\det(M)$, so we have
$$a^{-1}_{11} = \frac{\det(M)}{\det(A)}.$$

We know reach:
$$\det(B) = \left(1 + (d - a_{11})\frac{\det(M)}{\det(A)}\right)\det(A) = \det(A) + (d-a_{11})\det(M)$$
which is the same result Adam Latosiński got.